# MathNet.Numerics not utilizing the Mkl native provider

Tags: f#, blas, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I have an F# project that uses MathNet.Numerics for Linear Algebra routines.

I have placed the following code in an F# module:

```
module LinearAlgebra

open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Generic

Control.LinearAlgebraProvider <- new Algorithms.LinearAlgebra.Mkl.MklLinearAlgebraProvider()
```

But the times I am seeing for matrix multiplication remain the same whether I have this line of code enabled or commented out.

I have installed the Mkl provider NuGet package as described here:
http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/mathnet-numerics-with-native-linear-algebra.html

and have ensured that these two dlls are copied to the bin directory:
libiomp5md.dll
MathNet.Numerics.MKL.dll

Any ideas about how I can detect if the native provider is actually being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/docs/MKL.html) are a bit more up to date than the mentioned blog post, but it seems all the required steps have been done.

- How large are your matrices?
- Are all the involved matrices dense?
- Is this module the module where your linear algebra code is in? If not, have you made sure that this module is actually executed - before the linear algebra code?

You can verify the native provider is enabled by checking `Control.LinearAlgebraProvider` right before the linear algebra code is executed. In v3, calling `ToString` on it will provide some additional info like platform and revision as well.

Comment: Matrices are 4000x430 and 430x430.  I am using only dense matrix types, even though some are sparse in terms of structure.  As I understood, sparse is not working yet with native providers.  So if I set the MklProvider in the module where the calculations are made, it works.  But if I set it in another module and import that module, it does not work.  So I wrapped the call to set the provider in an init function and call that after opening the module, and that also works.  Must be something about F# modules that I am not aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, adding sparse support to the MKL native provider has been delayed to a minor release after v3.0.

Comment: Found the reason why the top level statement in the opened module was not working.  I had only inline functions in the module so it was never truly being opened prior to using the linear algebra provider.

Comment: By the way, a big "thanks" to the MathNet team for this library.